# Frost on my windshield at 40° f on a clear cold still morning?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, everyday-life

I LOVE this question/idea. So, how many different kinds of heating and cooling are there? If the "radiative" cooling or temperature of a clear night sky can be minus 60, how come I'm not flash frozen? Are different kinds of heat loss stronger than other kinds of heat loss? What is the relative strength of different kinds of heat loss?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, different kinds of heating/cooling ([heat transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer)) have different "strengths".

Contact heating/cooling is when you touch a warm/cold object and heat flows from the warm to the cold side. This can be very efficient if the object has a high [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities) like metal: a lot of heat energy can be moved at a given temperature difference if you touch metal, while a low conductivity material like air doesn't transfer much.

Convective heating/cooling happens when some fluid or gas flows past, constantly picking up or leaving heat. [How much is transferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) depends on the material - water can transport 5-100 times more than air - but also how rapidly the heat is moved away.

Evaporative cooling happens when moisture evaporates, which picks up some heat. This is usually less effective than the previous, but if there is air constantly removing the moisture or it is really hot moisture it can still cool quite a bit. If the moisture is really hot. In general there are various options for heating/cooling based on phase transitions where materials pick up or leave heat.

Finally there is radiative cooling/heating, where the energy comes in as electromagnetic waves (usually mostly infrared, but in principle firing a laser at something is a heating method). It is usually the weakest of these heat transfer modes. It becomes very effective at very high temperatures, but at everyday temperatures conduction and convection dominates.